# "Red-marked copy": A draft text with changes highlighted?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I always thought of "red-marked copy" as a standard way of referring to a draft text in which the changes from a previous draft are highlighted. After casually using it when talking to a fellow member (BE as first language) of the university lab I am working at and generating confusion, [I looked it up on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22red-marked%20copy%22) and discovered that there are only about 2k results found.

So I am wondering:

1. Is "red-marked copy" a common expression? Is there any meaning other than a copy tracking changes by highlighting?
2. Is there a more universally accepted term to refer to a copy tracking changes to a document?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "Marked-up copy" is a term I've heard of, but I'm not sure about relative popularity. https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100134874

Comment: marked-up copy, yes. Lawyers use: red-lining and black-lining. Copy with tracked changes turned on. I think you can use any color you like....[Personally, I detest that track changes feature.]

Comment: @StuartF Does "marked-up copy" sound disparaging to you? Mark up is defined [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mark+up) as "to deface by covering with marks" and "deface" is definitely not an appreciation...

Comment: In the editing world, we do say: this is marked-up copy. To mark copy, with the marks used in correcting texts. So Stuart F is absolutely right.

Comment: @Lambie [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_comparison) claims that black-lining originates from monochrome replication of red-lining... Which also suggests that the term has been around long before the ascent of word processing software with those either beloved or hated features to track changes...

Comment: @Lambie My question is whether marked-up copy is a neutral comment or a criticism (be it of the editor or the original author...) that there are too many marks. In the editing world, do you see it as judgmental? As "deface" might make me believe?

Comment: The point of using "marked-up" as a modifier is simply to distinguish an edited manuscript in which the changes are visible from a "raw" (unedited) manuscript and a "cleaned-up" manuscript (one in which the editing changes have been accepted or otherwise incorporated without leaving them visible). Used in this sense, "marked-up" is a purely descriptive term and doesn't imply a negative judgment about the quality of the manuscript. I haven't encountered the expression "red-marked copy" in my editing work, but I don't see anything wrong with it as a descriptive phrase.